# Uncaught Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in github actions

Tags: mysql, node.js, github, github-actions

hi it's my first time using GitHub actions and I've hit a bit of a snag ive looked all over the internet but cant figure it out. Im trying to test a node.js api with a mysql db. So far no luck even root cant access it for some reason. please help! I have console.loged the process.env and put them in the comments

```
on: [push]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [12.x]

    services:
      mysql:
        image: mysql:5.7
        env:
          DB_HOST: localhost
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
         
          DB_NAME: heroku_b5b309c959adca7
          MYSQL_Grant: SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, RELOAD, PROCESS, REFERENCES, INDEX, ALTER, SHOW DATABASES, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE, REPLICATION SLAVE, REPLICATION CLIENT, CREATE VIEW, SHOW VIEW, CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE, CREATE USER, EVENT, TRIGGER ON *.* TO 'b734bbe733ac95'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION

        ports:
          - 3306
        options: --health-cmd="mysqladmin ping" --health-interval=10s --health-timeout=5s --health-retries=3

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      - name: npm install, build, and test
        run: |
            npm install
            sudo service mysql start
            #mysql --host 127.0.0.1 --port ${{ job.services.mysql.ports['3306'] }} -uroot -ppassword  -e "CREATE USER 'myuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'passthatword';"
            mysql --host 127.0.0.1 --port ${{ job.services.mysql.ports['3306'] }} -uroot -ppassword  -e "SELECT host,user,authentication_string FROM mysql.user"
            mysql --host 127.0.0.1 --port ${{ job.services.mysql.ports['3306'] }} -uroot -ppassword  -e "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS db"
            #mysql --host 127.0.0.1 --port ${{ job.services.mysql.ports['3306'] }} -uroot -ppassword  -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'myuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'passthatword' WITH GRANT OPTION;"
            mysql --host 127.0.0.1 --port ${{ job.services.mysql.ports['3306'] }} -uroot -ppassword  -e "SHOW DATABASES"
            mysql --host 127.0.0.1 --port ${{ job.services.mysql.ports['3306'] }} -uroot -ppassword  -e "SHOW GRANTS"
            mysql --host 127.0.0.1 --port ${{ job.services.mysql.ports['3306'] }} -uroot -ppassword -Ddb < database.sql
            mysql --host 127.0.0.1 --port ${{ job.services.mysql.ports['3306'] }} -uroot -ppassword -Ddb < testing_with_all_tables.txt
            npm test
```

[image: error file]

db_connection.js

```
const mysql = require("mysql2");
const dbConfig = require("../config/db.general.config.js");
// Create a connection to the database
const connection = mysql.createPool({
  connectionLimit: 100,
  host: dbConfig.HOST,
  user: dbConfig.USER,
  password: dbConfig.PASSWORD,
  database: dbConfig.DB,
  port: dbConfig.port,
  debug: false,
});
// open the MySQL connection
connection.getConnection(function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected!");
});
module.exports = connection;
```

dbConfig file

```
module.exports = {
  HOST: process.env.DB_HOST || 'localhost',
  USER: process.env.DB_USER || 'root',
  PASSWORD: process.env.DB_PASSWORD || 'passthatword',
  DB:   process.env.DB_NAME || 'database',
  port: process.env.DB_PORT || '3306',
};
```

Comment: Something looks wrong with your structure..  steps and services should be nested inside of jobs. Copy paste error? There's a github actions linter somewhere out there too

Comment: oh it is on here ill fix it @Evert

Comment: I didn't realize this right away, but it looks like that error is emitted from your test, which means that _all_ the `mysql` commands earlier all worked, so mysql is definitely set up right. How are you connecting to mysql? Also using `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` may help

Comment: @Evert i tried changing all the localhosts sadly it didn't work. ill give it one more shot as for how I'm connecting here's a version of my db connection file

Comment: yup still same error

Comment: ALso sahre the contents of `dbConfig`. might help to `console.log` that object so you can see what's _really_ set in Github actions

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247234/discussion-between-wasi-hassan-and-evert).